# Position of Leap point not in sync with THREEJS Scene

Tags: 3d, three.js, coordinates, leap-motion

I've been trying my darnedest to get the position presented by the RiggedHand mesh to accurately create small spheres in a THREEJS scene. I'm trying to do this at the position of a given fingertip. The X, and Y seem correct but the Z is almost always off. More importantly, the further it goes away from the center, the skew is even more pronounced (i.e. the X, and Y are off too).

The best I've been able to do is figure out the 'right' coordinates using the following code:

```
var handMesh = hand.data('riggedHand.mesh'); 
//This is the best I've gotten so far with the position of the fingertip
var position = handMesh.fingers[1].tip.getWorldPosition();
```

Not really sure what the best way to do this is, but I've tried several so far. Converting the hand.finger[x].tipPosition, using the interactionbox and multiplying by the windowsize to try to get an accurate position. I'm starting to wonder if it has more to do with the fact that I'm using PerspectiveCamera in THREEJS and that I need to compensate for it somehow (?) - really not sure which way to go about this but hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

A full snippet of sample code where the above is used is as follows:

```
    var renderer, scene, camera, riggedHandPlugin, fadingSpheres
    var sphereTTL = 7;

    function initScene() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 200;
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcccccc, 0.002);

        var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        scene.add(light);

        // renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: false });

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        container = document.getElementById('container');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        fadingSpheres = [];
    }

    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        if (fadingSpheres) {
            fadingSpheres.forEach(removeDeadSpheres);
        }
    }

    function FadingSphere(position, size, meshColor) {
        //Draw the sphere at the position of the indexfinger tip position
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 8, 8);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: meshColor});

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        mesh.material.ambient = mesh.material.color;

        mesh.position.x = position.x;
        mesh.position.y = position.y;
        mesh.position.z = position.z;

        this.sphere = mesh;

        scene.add(this.sphere);
        fadingSpheres.push(this);

        this.ttl = sphereTTL;
        this.updateToRemove = function () {
            this.ttl--;
            return (this.ttl <= 0);
        }
    }

    function removeDeadSpheres(fadingSphere, number, array) {
        if (fadingSphere) {
            if (fadingSphere.updateToRemove()) {
                scene.remove(fadingSphere.sphere);
                var index = array.indexOf(fadingSphere);
                array.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //Within the leap draw loop
    //Leap loop to call drawing functions
    Leap.loop(
      function (frame) {
          frame.hands.forEach(
            function (hand) {
                var handMesh = hand.data('riggedHand.mesh');

                function createSphereAtFingerTip(fingerIndex, colorHex) {
                    new FadingSphere(handMesh.fingers[fingerIndex].tip.getWorldPosition(), 3, colorHex);
                }

                createSphereAtFingerTip(0, 0xF57E20) //Thumb
                createSphereAtFingerTip(1, 0xFFCC00) //Index
                createSphereAtFingerTip(2, 0xCCCC51) //Middle
                createSphereAtFingerTip(3, 0x8FB258) //Ring
                createSphereAtFingerTip(4, 0x336699) //pinky
            }
       )
      }
    )
    .use('riggedHand')
    .use('handEntry')

    riggedHandPlugin = Leap.loopController.plugins.riggedHand;

    initScene();
    render();
```

Would appreciate any and all suggestions/advice that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it thanks to Peter's last example. It was Test 3 that helped me find out the issue.

The problem actually was that I seem to have been using a different 'scene' (variable aptly named) than the scene that the rigged hand was using. I didn't realize they were different (doh!). I switched it over to use the riggedHand.parent as the 'scene' instead of the scene instance I created manually within initScene(), which now has a parameter to which I pass in riggedHand.parent as the scene to use the first time it's available.

```
function initScene(basisScene) {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, sceneArea / 100,
      sceneArea * 4);
    camera.position.z = sceneArea;
    scene = basisScene;
```

The OTHER thing was to not call the renderer.render(scene, camera); within the render() loop - even after 'scene' was set from riggedHand.parent. I didn't realize the leap frame(?) made it unnecessary to have to call renderer.render anymore.

```
    function render() {
        //Next line no longer needed:
        //renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
```

The updated code with the fading spheres is up at: http://codepen.io/GMelencio/pen/EaWqjZ

Thanks again Peter!

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the rigged hand plugin: The skinned mesh model unfortunately has (slightly) different proportions from the hand data returned by the Leap Motion API.  This means that for a given pose the tip of the mesh's bone and the tip position data as returned by the API will be near eachother, but different.

(Internally, the plugin works by calculating the correct angles from bone to bone, which are then fed to the THREE.js Skinning API)

You can actually view the offsets with this example: http://leapmotion.github.io/leapjs-rigged-hand/?dots=1

Is this what you're experiencing?  I think that knowing this, you should be able to get either the correct LM positions, or visually correct skinned mesh positions.  It's also possible that the mesh could be deformed programmatically, or remodeled, to fit the LM data more accurately. (See the [creating rigged hands wiki](https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs-rigged-hand/wiki/Creating-Rigged-Hands).)

Comment: Thanks Peter! My problem actually seems more pronounced than what your shows. I've put up a sample of my code here  http://gmelencio.github.io/

Comment: As you can see from my example at [link](http://gmelencio.github.io) the spheres drawn at the finger "tip" positions from the mesh are entirely off. However, this is the closest I've ever gotten to simulating the correct position of the finger points relative to the mesh. I feel like there's something fundamental that I'm missing; if I can even get the spheres to be as close to the rigged hand mesh in your example - I feel that there's something fundamental I'm missing with using Leap vs THREEJS, if I can get to as close as where you were I'd be happy enough!

Comment: Note, replaced link from the above with this: http://codepen.io/GMelencio/pen/QwdzYp

Comment: Alright!  There was a(nother) bug in the riggedHand plugin, which caused the "dots" to be offset even more than expected.  I've released 0.1.6, and updated your example to demo it.  The plugin itself has been simplified to not manage data transformations: raw leap data should be usable, un-modified.
-------
In this pen, I've added three tests at the bottom. 1: the boneHand plugin overlaying the rigged hand, 2: a white sphere, 3: the white sphere inside the main loop.
-------
http://codepen.io/leapmotion/pen/QwderK
-------
Something's still up w/ the FadingSphere, but I think that may be on you